# Where do I check message from an app request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, apprequests

So...when I sent a app request with the following code, there's a message field. Where do I check it on my facebook? I receive an app request, but I don't see the message that I sent.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: message,
      data: {
      }
}, showRequestDialogCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

does 'message' have any value?

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'you need to write a message here!',
      data: {
      }
}, showRequestDialogCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant to you but just in case anybody has the same issue:

From my experience and from reading the [Facebook Developer Guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), it seems like it's mandatory for you to have a Canvas defined for your Facebook app so the requests render as Notifications.

I am trying to solve a problem where these notifications show fine in the Facebook website but not on the Facebook Android client's notification popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you send an `apprequest` to a user which hasn't installed your application yet the `message` parameter will be ignored and therefore not displayed in the actual notification.

[Request Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)